# Java Dialog setModal

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, glasspane

Related to my previous question [Java Project - how to freeze Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835092/java-project-how-to-freeze-frame),
Is it possible to darken the color of the main screen (make EVERYTHING gray or black and white) to highlight the player dialog box? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Glass Pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) example for a complete example and explanation.

In general your glass pane can use an transparent background:

```
JComponent glassPane = new JPanel();
glassPane.setBackground( new Color(240, 20, 20, 100) );
frame.setGlassPane( glassPane );
```

Then when you want to show the dialog the basic code would be:

```
glassPane.setVisible( true );
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(...);
// add components to dialog
dialog.setVisible( true );
glassPane.setVisible( false );
```